# Java and MySQL connection pool: avoid timeouts

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, connection-pooling

I've been trying to Tomcat's native conncetion pooling features to avoid connection timeouts in my Java web project, but it seems I'm still out of luck.

I've put `mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar` in the `WEB-INF/lib` folder, created a `META-INF/context.xml` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/TheDatabase" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="1000"
            poolPreparedStatements="true" maxOpenPreparedStatements="100"
            username="user" password="pass"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database"/>
</Context>
```

Here's what I do:

```
public static init() {
    ...
    sqlDataSource = (DataSource) new InitialContext().lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/TheDatabase");
    ...
}

public static ArrayList<ResultSet> dbRead() {
    Connection conn = sqlDataSource.getConnection();
    Statement stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM the_table");
        ...
        res.close();

        return out;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Logging stuff
        return null;
    } finally {
        if (stmt != null)
            try {if (!stmt.isClosed()) stmt.close();}
            catch (SQLException e) {/* Logging stuff */}
        if (conn != null)
            try {if (!conn.isClosed()) conn.close();}
            catch (SQLException e) {/* Logging stuff */}
    }
}
```

Whenever I call the function `dbRead` after the `wait_timeout` has passed, I get:

```
Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 1.818.697 milliseconds
ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago.
```

with a SQL state `08S01`.

I thought it was because of some uncorrect closings, but it doesn't seem the case.

Comment: @duffymo It *was* actually answered there, even though the answer wasn't accepted. Too bad I couldn't find that question in my searches (that maybe were too refined). I'll do some additional tests, then add the answer, then this question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seemed that all I needed to add to the `<Resource>` definition was the `validationQuery` attribute. No `autoReconnect`, no `autoReconnectForPools`, nothing. This just works:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TheDatabase" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="1000"
        poolPreparedStatements="true" maxOpenPreparedStatements="100"
        username="user" password="pass" validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_database"/>
```

That attribute isn't even in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html), so I had no idea of its existence. Now I doubt some of the other attributes have any effect too...

Comment: It's not a MySQL property, that's why you didn't find it there. It's a property of Apache DBCP.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding **a validation query** and let me now.I hope this will solve the problem.
If not then **change the localhost to the IP** of your machine(you may also test 127.0.0.1)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/TheDatabase" auth="Container"
            type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="1000"
            poolPreparedStatements="true" maxOpenPreparedStatements="100"
            username="user" password="pass" validationQuery="select now()" 
            url="jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.1:3306/my_database"/>
</Context>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the autoReconnect to true the default is false.
for more inforamtion or help

**autoReconnect**   Should the driver try to re-establish stale and/or dead connections? If enabled the driver will throw an exception for a queries issued on a stale or dead connection, which belong to the current transaction, but will attempt reconnect before the next query issued on the connection in a new transaction. The use of this feature is not recommended, because it has side effects related to session state and data consistency when applications don't handle SQLExceptions properly, and is only designed to be used when you are unable to configure your application to handle SQLExceptions resulting from dead and stale connections properly. Alternatively, as a last option, investigate setting the MySQL server variable "wait_timeout" to a high value, rather than the default of 8 hours.   false   1.1

**autoReconnectForPools**   Use a reconnection strategy appropriate for connection pools (defaults to 'false')  false   3.1.3

[see mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, I get the exact same error. That's odd, it doesn't seem that those properties have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this Stuff:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/myDataSource" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
            maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
            username="user" password="pass" 
            driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
            url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/my_database?autoReconnect=true"
            logAbandoned="true" removeAbandoned="true" 
            removeAbandonedTimeout="60" />
```

Comment: Tried, but with no luck. I've tried using the attribute `autoReconnect` instead of the parameter, and using `autoReconnectForPools` too, but the result is the same.

Comment: the same error generate ?

Comment: Yes, the same `Communications link failure` error.